# Condition of pushward commutes with tensor product

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, coherent-sheaves

Let $f$ be a morphism between schemes. Is there a sufficient and necessary condition on $f$ such that $f_*$ commutes with $\otimes$? i.e.
$$f_*F\otimes f_*G\cong f_*(F\otimes G)$$
for all coherent sheaves $F,G$.

In particular, I want to know that is it true for $f$ proper.

Comment: This is rarely true and properness is insufficient. For a simple example, take $f:\mathbb{P}^1_k\to k$ and $F=O(-1), G=O(1)$.

Comment: @Mohan Emmm... I see. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe we can say that a necessary and sufficient condition on $f$ is being a monomorphism. But my argument is incomplete : if $f$  into on closed points, so there is two closed points $x\neq y$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$. Then take the skyscraper sheaves at $x$ and $y$. We have $\kappa(x)\otimes\kappa(y)=0$ since they are supported on different points. But $f_*\kappa(x)\otimes f_*\kappa(y)=\kappa(f(x))\otimes \kappa(f(x))=\kappa(f(x))$. Conversely, if moreover $A$ is affine (like most monomorphisms ?), then the problem reduces to a problem on modules which is easy.

Comment: @Mohan or even: $f\colon\{*\}\sqcup\{*\}\to\{*\}$, and $F$ and $G$ are the structure sheaf on $\{*\}\sqcup\{*\}$.